# Laravel 5.4. Политика авторизации не применяется в контроллере

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток. Не применяется политика, если в контроллере использовать `$this->authorize()`, вызванный в конструкторе. Я создал:

- модель **Announce**;
- политика **AnnouncePolicy**
- контроллер **AnnounceController** (ресурс)

С помощью директивы @can в видах получается обратиться к политике:

```
@can('create', App\Page::class)
    <li class="active"><a href="{{ route('announces.create') }}">Создать объявление</a></li>
@endcan
```

С помощью фасада Gate, в действиях контроллера, тоже работает.

Как "распостранить" политику на весь контроллер, а не прописывать
`Gate::denies('create', App\Page::class);`
в каждом действии контроллера?

```
AnnounceController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
      $this->authorize(Announce::class); //не работает
  }

//...
```

По документации, если передать просто объект (или название класса) в метод контроллера `authorize()`, то он должен брать правило политики (create, в нашем случае), из названия действия контроллера. Более того, в коде фреймворка (уже не помню, где) видел карту вроде

```
[
   //предположительно:
   //политика => действие resource-контроллера
   'create'=>'create'
   'create'=>'store'
   'update'=>'edit'
   'update'=>'update'
]
```

это может значить, что эти политики должны распостраняться не только на одноименные методы.

Я только начинаю учить Laravel. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкторе контроллера авторизация доступна не будет. Лучше политику применить в middleware и использовать middleware в конструкторе контроллера